# Cordova Firebase Social OAuth Not Utilizing Browser Sessions

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

In my Cordova/Angular/Firebase app, the social login redirect pages keep requiring me to enter credentials for the social platform, even though I'm logged in for these sites in Safari already.

I recently upgraded my Cordova app to AngularFire 2.x.x and Firebase 4.x.x and I'm trying to implement the social login functionality as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

When I test on-device, the login opens in what looks like a Safari View Controller, but for Facebook, Twitter, & Google login, the pages require re-entering credentials. I was under the impression that the Safari View Controller would reuse session data from the Safari app itself. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I think this behavior may have changed in iOS 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @bojeil above led me to this documentation:

https://blog.branch.io/ios-11-safari-view-controller-cookie-passthrough-and-the-future-of-mobile-web/

This is new expected behavior in iOS 11.